# Inconsistent display of multi-line rtl SVG text between browsers

Tags: svg, text, multiline, right-to-left

I'm working with `tspan` elements and trying to display rtl text correctly but it's showing up to be inconsistent between browsers

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 171.6875 162.84375" width="171.6875" height="162.84375">
  <text font-size="72" font-family="Arial" fill="red" x="0" y="70.234375" text-anchor="start"  >
    <tspan x="0%" dy="0">تونس</tspan>
    <tspan x="0%" dy="72">السلام</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etxs3vz7/4/)

When I add a ltr character at the end of the second word, the text displays correctly across all major browsers
Is there a way to add an invisible ltr char as a workaround?

I tried `direction="rtl"` and `writing-mode="rl"` without any effect on Chrome

Comment: Unicode U+200E [Left-to-right-mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: That's awesome, please compose an answer, I will accept it right away

Comment: I'd rather leave an answer to someone who really knows why the inconsistency happens in the first place.

Comment: yeah, it only displays correctly on Firefox

Comment: SVG text has a lot of bugs ...

Comment: It's a bit like a minefield. I ended up using the left-to-right marker at the beginning and end of each `tspan` and it solved me issue https://jsfiddle.net/etxs3vz7/6/

Comment: I add the lrm in JS like this: `String.fromCharCode(8206)`